# SEO - Getting a 301 page indexed by search engines

Tags: http-status-code-301, seo

I have a site (say **site1.com**) which 301-redirects to another page on a different site (say **http://site2.com/some/dirty/url**).

**Typical code at site1.com:**

```
<?php 
    header("HTTP/1.1 301"); header("refresh:0;url=http://site2.com/some/dirty/url");
?><html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Site 1 - heading.
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="some description" />
    </head>
    <body />
</html>
```

Typically, Search Engines never index **site1.com**, even when there are external links like:

```
<a href="http://site1.com/">Click Here</a>
```

But this is considered as an external link to **http://site2.com/some/dirty/url** and thus **http://site2.com/some/dirty/url** is seo'd.

I some how want to get **site1.com** indexed (Just the title, meta description and URL) though **http://site2.com/some/dirty/url** getting indexed is not a problem. Is this really possible or is it just what I have to forget about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,It can be indexed......But it requires a better on page work on the both of your sites 
(http://site.com) and (http://site2.com/some/dirty/url) .............

For example I have recently worked on the same conditions the website url is "http://www.top-alliance.de" which redirects to "http://www.top-alliance.com" and these both sites are indexed by the search engine recently by 04 June 2012.This is happened because i have done a better onpage work for both pages...

So the conclusion is the both your sites will require better on page work so it will definitely indexed by the search engine.

Thanks & Regards

Nitin Bhatnagar

Comment: It needs a simple on page work as every one do in their site for more help you can check my above example sites on page....

Comment: is it not a violation of TOS of the search engines?

Comment: Yes it can be so you can do one more thing to avoid this problem that you will change all the Title,Keywords and descriptions in both the domain pages.

Answer (score 3):

The 301 redirect tells search engines, and any other user agent that respects HTTP status codes, that `http://site.com` no longer exists and has moved to a new location. This means they now consider the new location of `http://site.com` to be `http://site2.com/some/dirty/url` and to associate everything, including all links to `http://site.com` to be associated with `http://site2.com/some/dirty/url`. So basically `http://site.com` does not exist anymore and  no matter how many links you point to it, it won't change anything since they now will be associated with `http://site2.com/some/dirty/url`. And that makes sense since a 301 HTTP status does indicate that a page has moved permanently. If that page hasn't moved permanently then you are using the wrong HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

To easily create redirects in your WordPress, an alternative is a simple 301 redirect plugin. Once you've installed and activated the plugin, add a new menu in the Settings area of ​​your dashboard.

There is really nothing to worry about with this plugin. The 301 Redirect Configuration window shows you two simple fields. One labeled as a request and the other as a destination. This is basically where the old permanent link structure and the new permanent link structure come from. You only need to add information after your domain name in these fields.

In the example above, the request field is the WordPress setting for the month and name Permilix, while the destination field is the WordPress setting for the post name Permalink structure. After you add these two fields, save your changes. It will ask any search engine traffic to come back to the old links.